# Sending file info via jQuery to get processed by a PHP script

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but here is what I have so far:

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image_upload" />
<button id="submit" />
<div id="display"></div>
```

Here's the jQuery, but this is sending as POST data and of course it's not actually getting the file info as far as I can tell. Is there a way to send this via AJAX to my upload.php script?

```
// Send ajax data to create option in store
$('#submit').live('click', function() {
    var file = $('#image_upload').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: "file="+file,
        success: function(html){
             $('#display').html(html);

         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout http://www.uploadify.com/ , reinventing the wheel (and especially this wheel) is often tedious and will for sure get you frustrated.

To further this point, it is not currently possible to upload files via XMLHttpRequest(aka AJAX). You can fake it(POST to an iframe for example) in many different ways, which uploadify actually does quite well.

Good Luck!

Edit:

Solution that doesn't use flash:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: Yea, flash based options are not viable for what I'm doing.

Comment: Updated answer to provide non-flash solution.